# Unwanted Session duplication in Django

Tags: django, session, redis, session-hijacking

We're using cached_db as our SESSION_ENGINE.
We have a session duplication issue, this is the scenario:

1. User 1 is browsing the system.
2. User 2 is browsing and modifying his session.
3. User 1 continuing browsing and finds that his session changed to User's 2 session.

If we use SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST then it works fine but we want to fix this problem from the source.

We are using Django 1.6 with Redis

Comment: You really should upgrade... at least to Django-1.11 https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/ Django-1.6 is no longer supported since April 2015.

Comment: Could you provide session related code?